# Loop by taking variable values

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to write bash script and how can i take values defined in variable in pipe delimiter format and print them. 
Below is the algorithm i am thinking, but not sure about bash commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
variable1="A|B|C"

if [ ! -z "$variable1" ]
   count=#should return 3 as there are 3 values (A|B|C)
fi

while count>0; do
derivedvariable=#should get A, B, C in loop
print $derivedvariable
done
```

```
output should be: 
A
B
C
```

Comment: What are you REALLY trying to do? Do you want to use arrays? Why are you using the `find` command on a variable? Did you want `awk` like `awk -F"|" '{print NF}'` to get your count? Is `A|B|C` a string literal? Why is it not in quotes? What, again, are you really trying to do here?

Comment: the `find` command is for listing filenames that match criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IFS` to specify the field separator when splitting words after variable expansion.

```
variable1='A|B|C'
IFS='|'
for i in $variable1
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Like it. Simple and straight forward. Tested and working.

Answer (score 2):

Use array to store elements of your input delimited by a character:

```
s='A|B|C'
IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$s"

# length:
echo "${#arr[@]}"

# looping array:
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
done
```

**Output:**

```
3
A
B
C
```

Comment: I tried Barmar given answer. any reason why you used array ? Barmar didn't use array and how come the script is able to print each value ? explanation would be very helpful

Comment: From your question it appeared that you are also trying to use `count=` which is possible with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` or `tr`:

```
grep -o "[^|]*" <<< "${variable1}"

tr '|' '\n' <<< "${variable1}"
```

Comment: thanks, grep and tr is outputting what i required in one shot. but i need them in loop which i can pass them to other commands. thanks though.